# Accessing variable from outsite of axios post

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I'm trying to access a variable inside of axios call, but it returns an `undefined` error. Please see my code below.

```
new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data(){
     return {
       roles: [{ display: 'disp' }]
     }
   },
   methods: {
      axios.post('{{ route('role.add') }}', {

      })
      .then((response, roles) => {
            console.log(this.roles);

      })
       .catch(function(err){
          console.log(err);
       });
   }

})
```

**Error**

> Undefined

**Solution [SOLVED]**

- Added  global variable above the Vue.

Comment: Why `this.`, if you are trying to access what appears to be a simple local variable?

Comment: Or are you trying to access the parameter `roles` specified in the anonymous callback function declaration? Then `this.` would still be wrong. And I rather doubt if any such second parameter would get passed to the callback to begin with, I can’t see what here should trigger that in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe Please see my update.

Comment: what you want in you console

Answer (score 0):

Try to access without `this`. I don't see any purpose for using `this`.

```
const axios = require("axios");
var a = "some value";

axios.get('http://www.google.com').then(function () {

    console.log(a);
}).catch(e => {
    console.log(e, "ERROR");
})
```

Comment: try by accesing `roles` not  `this.roles`

Comment: I tried using `roles`, but I still get the same error.

Comment: promise can't resolve to both values, either add `[response, roles]` or `response` depending upon resolution. Maybe only `response`

Comment: You can access using `response.data.roles`. But I am not sure about reponse structure your route is sending

Answer (score 0):

Just remove this keyword and it will work:

```
var roles = [{ display: 'disp' }];

axios.post('{{ route('role.add') }}', {

})
.then(function(response){
     console.log(roles);
})
.catch(function(err){
     console.log(err);
});
```

Or use arrow function which is not preferred:

```
var roles = [{ display: 'disp' }];

axios.post('{{ route('role.add') }}', {

})
.then((response, roles) => {
     console.log(this.roles);
})
.catch(function(err){
     console.log(err);
});
```